# Android - Firebase many to many relationship child listener

Tags: android, firebase

My firebase database has the following structure:

```
tasks 
   - task_key_1:{
       - name: "task 1"
       - ...
       - users{
             user_key_1 : true
         }
   }

users
  - user_key_1{
        tasks{
             task_key_1 : true
        }
  }
```

Now, I would like to display a list of an user's tasks in an activity. I found this method and it's working:

```
myTasks.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            taskReference.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     ... 
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
                }
            });
        }

        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            taskReference.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                  ......
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
                }
            });

        }

        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        taskReference.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               Log.w(TAG, "on child changed")
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
            }
        });

            });
        }

        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onChildMoved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}

    });
```

where:
mytasks is a reference to /users/userId/tasks
and taskReference is /tasks/taskKeyOwnedByUser.

My problem is: how can I detect changes to a task, i.e. when the user changes its title, and then update the list UI? It seems that the "Log.w" inside OnChildChanged never gets called.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, change the value type of `users/<usersId>/tasks/<taskId>` to a timestamp value. Then when you are about to update the task, make sure to also update the timestamp so the `onChildChanged` will be triggered.

This is your database structure would be

```
users {
    - user_key_1 {
        tasks {
            task_key_1 : ServerValue.TIMESTAMP (Long value)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an example method when you are about to update the task's name

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("tasks/" + task_key + "/name", new_task_name);
values.put("users/" + user_key + "/tasks/" + task_key, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.updateChildren(values);
```

With this approach, the `onChildChanged` will be fired.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I was wondering though, maybe there is a way to do this using the "standard" keys created by firebase, without having to customize them.

Comment: @Spyga what keys do you mean? The task_key or?